# why is my pointer passing function giving me a wrong output?

Tags: c, pointers

the following is given

```
#include  <stdio.h>    
void func2 (int num, int *result);   
int main()    
{    
   int num, result;    

   printf("Enter a number: \n"); 
   scanf("%d", &num);
   func2(num, &result);    
   printf("func2(): %d\n", result);    
   return 0;    
}

void func2(int num, int *result)     
{    
//key in code    
}
```

in the void func2 i wrote

```
int i=0;    
result=&i;      
while (num!=0)    
{    
i+=((num%10)*(num%10));    
num=num/10;    
}
```

but the programming is not returning the value of variable i properly. what's wrong with my variable assignment?

expected output:

```
Enter a number:    
24 (user enter)    
func2(): 20
```

actual output:

```
Enter a number:    
24 (user enter)    
func2(): 32767
```

Comment: The psudo-code for `func2` never stores to `*result`, so any results ir produces will be unavailable to its caller.

Comment: Also, `num` is uninitialized.

Comment: added expected output and actual output.

Comment: is my num not initialized in my int main?

Comment: It's declared, never initialized. Global variables are automatically initialized to 0, local variables are not.

Comment: but i am assigning the address of i to results so shouldn't it work? or this setting of this question not really a pointer?

Comment: You need to do `*result = something` to change the variable in `main()`.

Comment: If you reassign `result`, you no longer have a pointer to the caller's variable.

Comment: oh then how can I initialized? since I am unable to edit the code that is provided.

Comment: It seems like you need to read a tutorial on pointers.

Comment: Are you sure you copied `main()` correctly? It says `Enter a number`, so I suspect there's supposed to be a line that takes user input and assigns it to `num`.

Comment: Like `scanf("%d", &num);`

Comment: As Tom and Barmar state, you need `*result = something`, not `result = something`, if you expect the original parameter to retain the assigned value.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for pointing it out. Edited. Didn't copy the code right. The actual output remains the same. I am fairly new at pointers. in my slides it is stated that if I were to do result=&i; both results and i will refer to the same memory content. is that wrong?

Comment: You may want to read about the difference between passing variables to functions [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm) and [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign indirectly through `result`, not set `result` to the address of another variable.

```
int i=0;    
while (num!=0)    
{    
    i+=((num%10)*(num%10));    
    num=num/10;    
}
*result = i;
```